# Oracle.DataAccess.Client and .NET Framework errors in Microsoft Excel

Tags: .net, excel, oracle, provider, odac

[WIN10 - 64Bit] 
I am trying to connect to Oracle (12c)  from Excel (64-Bit) but am having issues.

From the OTN I have installed

```
ODAC 12.2.0.1.0,
```

which includes:

```
          Oracle Data Provider for .NET 12.2.0.1.0
          Oracle Providers for ASP .NET 12.2.0.1.0
          Oracle Provider for OLE DB 12.2.0.1.0
          Oracle services for Microsoft Transaction Server 12.2.0.1.0
          Oracle Data Access Components Documentation for Visual Studio 12.2.0.1.0
          Oracle Universal Installer 12.2.0.1.0
          Oracle Windows Security Interface 12.2.0.1.0
          Oracle Instant Client 12.2.0.1.0
```

When trying to connect to an Oracle database within Excel I get multiple errors:

First, I Click on

```
Data > Get Data > From Database > From Oracle Database
```

A messagebox/error appears stating

```
The recommended provider("Oracle.DataAccess.Client") is not installed.  You 
can continue with your current provider, however it has been deprecated and 
may not work correctly.
```

I click

```
'OK'
```

An inputbox appears with title:

```
Oracle database
```

In the Server field I type:

```
%HOSTNAME%:%PORT%\%SERVICE_NAME%
```

A new error message appears:

```
"Unable to Connect"
"We encountered an error while tyring to connect."
Details: "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data 
Provider.. This is a configuration issue with the file 
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config'."
```

At this point I am unable to continue and cannot connect to the Oracle database.  Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error complains that the driver is missing altogether. Which ODAC version did you install, the 32-bit or 64-bit one? If you install the 32-bit version, a 64-bit Excel won't even see it

Comment: I assume you followed [this guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-an-oracle-database-power-query-d7fbd231-a705-4eb7-83b3-a66bfb678395?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) ?

Comment: Hello.  yes, thank you for the response. I installed the 64-bit ODAC that is listed on the guide you linked ( 64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) Xcopy for Windows x64)  I've tried releases: 4, 2, and 1, to no avail.  My machine is 64-bit.  Excel is 64-bit, and all providers I've tried are 64-bit as well.  I'm not sure what the .NET framework issue is.

Comment: My Excel is a different version but try Data > Get Data > From Database (perhaps "From Others sources" > Data Connection Wizard -> Other/Advanced (or similar). In the Wizard you should be able to select the "Oracle Provider for OLE DB"

Answer (score 0):

Excel is based on the old [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) technology, thus you cannot use the .NET based Oracle Data Provider for .NET.

Try the Oracle Provider for OLE DB (`OraOLEDB.Oracle`) or the Oracle ODBC driver, they should work.

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for the response.  I installed ODAC 12.2.0.1.0 which includes Oracle Provider for OLE DB 12.2.0.1.0.  The ODAC is what was recommended by excel, but for some reason it is not working correctly, due to a .NET issue.  Is there another step I am supposed to take after installing with the OUI?

Answer (score 0):

Install Oracle Client for Microsoft Tools:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/net-downloads.html